# Django MongoDB Engine DebugCursor "not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

Trying to serialize a MongoDB cursor in Django

```
import json
from pymongo import json_util

results = json.dumps(results, default=json_util.default, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Where the original `results` is something like

```
[{u'_id': ObjectId('4f7c0f34705ff8294a00006f'),
  u'identifier': u'1',
  u'items': [{u'amount': 9.99, u'name': u'PapayaWhip', u'quantity': 1}],
  u'location': None,
  u'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 4, 10, 7, 0, 596000),
  u'total': 141.25}]
```

***Edit***: Obtained by using something like

```
from django.db import connections

connection = connections['default']

results = connection.get_collection('papayas_papaya')
results = results.find({
    'identifier': '1',
})
```

Gives me

```
TypeError: <django_mongodb_engine.utils.DebugCursor object> is not JSON serializable
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Using [json_util](http://api.mongodb.org/python/1.7/api/pymongo/json_util.html) should serialize MongoDB *documents*, maybe my issue is that I'm trying to serliaze a *cursor*. (How do I get the document from the cursor? A simple *tuple* "cast"?)

Cheers!

Comment: In order to help you we're gonna need to at least see what code you run to obtain `result.`

Comment: @NolenRoyalty I already showed what `results` looks like; to obtain it I used regular PyMongo query. I've updated the question anyway :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to serialize just one piece of data?  If so, just change

```
results = results.find({
    'identifier': '1',
})
```

to

```
results = results.find_one({
    'identifier': '1',
})
```

(Although you really should make a distinction between your results and the variable representing your collection.)

If you are trying to serialize multiple pieces of data, you can keep the `find` and then iterate through the cursor and serialize each piece of data.

```
serialized_results = [json.dumps(result, default=json_util.default, separators=(',', ':')) for result in results]
```

Comment: Ended up casting the cursor to a tuple and JSON-dumping that. Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should really be using Django's serialization system, or a pluggable JSON-serialization app at least.